# Looking to find out how to find a timestamp for archived emails

Tags: email, timestamp

Is there a way to find out when an email was archived? I am looing for a timestamp of when the email was archived?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best webpage to solve your issue. https://www.lifewire.com/find-out-when-a-message-was-sent-exactly-in-gmail-1172041
I've also copied in the short version of the instructions so you can try it from here.

From Inbox by Gmail (on the Web)

1. Open the message in Inbox by Gmail.
2. Hover the mouse cursor over the time shown in the header area of the email message. The full date and time will appear.
3. To view the timestamp in the original message, click the three vertically stacked dots (displayed as a tri-colon or a vertical ellipsis) next to the date.
4. Select Show original.
5. Find the timestamp next to Created at.